# Determining ring of invariants of $\pm$ Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-groups, invariant-theory

> Determine the ring of invariants $\mathbb C [x,y,z]^\Gamma$ for:
>
> $$\Gamma :=\{ 
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         \pm1 & 0 & 0 \\
>         0 & \pm1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & \pm1 \\
>         \end{pmatrix} \} \subset GL_3(\mathbb C).$$

So I read this as: what 3x3 invertible matrices (with columns x,y,z) multiplied by $\pm$ Identity stays the same? The only thing that stays the same when multiplied by both +1 and -1 is $0$. That's a very small ring. Am I misunderstanding this? How should I be tackling this problem?

Comment: I think $g \in \Gamma$ is supposed to act by the homomorphism induced by sending the vector $\left[ \begin{matrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right]$ to $g \left[ \begin{matrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: I would interpret this assignment as: *find the subring of $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ fixed by the homomorphism $x \mapsto - x, y \mapsto -y, z \mapsto -z$*. In particular, every polynomial of even degree will be an element of this ring (I think that the converse should be true, too, but I didn't check).

Comment: @A.P.: I read the notation as meaning a group of order 8, not a group of order 2.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I'm used to write, e.g., $(\pm1, \pm 1)$ for $(1,1),(-1,-1)$, not for $(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1)(-1,-1)$. Do you use the second convention?

Comment: @A.P.: I see both used and one has to infer from context... in this particular context, my inference is cemented by the fact that the source *could* have written other things to denote a group of order $2$, such as $\pm \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl You mean instead of a 3x3 being multiplied by identity, i'm looking for 3x1 multiplied by all of those 8 matrices? Again how can there be anything but zero as an answer?

Comment: @user20467: The polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ contains more elements than just the $\mathbb{C}$-linear combinations of $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: In case it's still not clear, an example is if $g$ is the matrix with signature $-,+,+$, then the corresponding action on polynomials is $g \cdot f(x,y,z) = f(-x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the group of order $8$, the invariants are $\mathbb C[x^2,y^2,z^2]$.

For the group $\pm I$ of order $2$, the invariants are $\mathbb C[\text{ even degree polynomials }]=\mathbb C[x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,yz,zx]$.

Comment: Hi ASCIIAdvocate. How did you arrive at this?

Comment: The action on any monomial is a 1-dimensional representation of the group, with different group elements acting by +1 or -1.   From this it is easy to identify the invariant subring.  Not fundamentally different than the case of 1 variable where there are odd and even polynomial functions, and those have a simple description in terms of which monomials they contain.

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate, please note that your comment is quite hard to parse for people not familiar with representation theory, which I assume is the OP's case. Could you edit you answer exemplifying the computations in one of the two cases?

Comment: A restatement is "every monomial is sent to +1 or -1 times itself by the different elements of the group, and that makes the analysis about the same as that of $x \to -x$ acting on $C[x]$". @A.P.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be Reinolds average operator for the group $\Gamma$
$$
R=\frac{1}{8} \sum_{g \in  \Gamma} g.
$$
For example, we have

$R(x)=R(y)=R(z)=0,$

$R(xy)=R(yz)=R(xz)=R(xyz)=0,$

$R(x^2)=x^2, R(y^2)=y^2,R(z^2)=z^2.$

It is a proector from algebra  $C[x,y,z]$  into the algebra $C[x,y,z]^{\Gamma}.$  Also, $C[x,y,z]^{\Gamma}$ is generated by invariants polynomials up to degree $8$ (the  Noether's  bound). So, the generating set of  algebra of invariants  $C[x,y,z]^{\Gamma}$ consists of all the elements $R(x^\alpha y^\beta  z^\gamma)$, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma\leq 8.$

Also, for  the operator $R$ we have that $R(f \cdot a)=a \cdot R(f),$ for any invariants $a \in C[x,y,z]^{\Gamma}.$

Now, by direct calculation you may get that  all invariants of to degree $8$ has the form $x^{2i} y^{2j} z^{2k}, i+j+k \leq 4.$ Thus  $C[x,y,z]^{\Gamma}=C[x^2,y^2,z^2].$